# View Moves After addSubview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, addsubview

I have a `UIImageView` and on top of it a `UITextView`, I need to take a screenShot of the image and the text together and for that I need the text to be inside the `UIImageView` so I use `imageView.addSubview(textView)`.

The problem is that when I use addSubview the textView jumps down and left and is no more on top of the imageView.

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: How did you set textView frame?

Comment: Can you please show your code? May be some problem with setting frame of UItextview. Please set textview origin (x,y) = (0,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sole purpose is to show a text over image then you should rather use `UILabel` like this:

```
// Add image view
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height)];
[self.view addSubView:myImageView];

// Now lets add label
UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myImageView.frame.origin.x + (myImage.size.width / 2), myImageView.frame.origin.y + (myImage.size.height / 2), 50, 15)];
test.text = @"Image Caption";
[self.view addSubview:testLabel];
```

Basic rule is UI components are layer by layer with last added component coming top in the layer and then by merging all the layers comes the final UI. Here I am just adding label after adding image with frame set middle to image. Hope you got it.